# random transformation parameters for each epoch in tensorflow dataset pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, input, pipeline

In my training, I need to get a new set of random data transformation parameters for each epoch and apply those (see below, for each iteration I try to generate a new mapping function). But this gives a `NotFoundError` and says `Function tf_data_structured_function_wrapper_P4jUpdWmQYM is not defined` for the second iteration (not for the first iteration), and it's coming from the `get_next()` method. How can I achieve my purpose? (Note: using the tensorflow random() method will return a different random number for each batch instead of each epoch, so that's a no)

```
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure((tf.float32, tf.float32))
next_element = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
for i in range(2):
    dataset1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).map(lambda x, y: (x + random(), y))
    initializer = iterator.make_initializer(dataset1)
    sess.run(initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            print(sess.run(next_element))
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```